# Classical derivative of convolution via weak derivative.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, convolution, weak-derivatives

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Differentiation) it is written that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(f\ast g)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\ast g=f\ast \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i} $$
"hold under the precise condition that $f$ and $g$ are absolutely integrable and at least one of them has an absolutely integrable ($L^1$) weak derivative,  as a consequence of Young's inequality".

My question: is that partial derivative for the convolution, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(f\ast g),$$ in the classical sense? If so, what is the exact proof of this statement?

Comment: Yes, it does appear to be in the 'classical sense'. The standard proof is to utilize the Convolution Theorem with Fourier Transforms (you are working with $L^1$ functions, so you know this is okay to do). There are plenty of proofs on Stack Exchange as well as many other spots if you need more detail.

Comment: @infinitylord Thanks for your comment. Could you indicate a link for the proof? I searched in Math Exchange before asking the question, but it is usually assumed that $f$ is $C^1$ with bounded partial derivatives.